# Hadoop - sharing files between multiple jobs in a chain

Tags: hadoop

I have written a map-reduce application that consists of two map-reduce phases.

binary input file -> m1-> r1 -> m2 -> r2 -> text output

The input file to my application contains a small chunk of data (<1k) that is needed by the second reducer (r2).  I have written a custom record reader that extracts this data, but then how do I pass this along to the next job?  It seems like this is a job for DistributedCache, but it appears that DistributedCache cache files are scoped to a single job's scratch space.  What is the best way to share small data between different jobs in the same chain?

Answer (score 0):

Try hadoop with -files option
I had similar issue in past and -files option worked for me.
Have a look [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/commands_manual.html#Generic+Options)

Comment: I've used the -files option before, the problem is that the file I would like to share is generated by the first phase of the map-reduce pipeline.  In other words, I don't have the file available on the client in able to use the -file option on the command line.